# Lombok issues with boolean property while using with JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, lombok

I have a REST payload which has a `boolean` property. And am using Lombok @Data since it is handy. However this is resulting in unexpected behaviour while working with JAX-RS. Below is the POJO used as REST payload:

```
@Data
public class Foo implements Serializable { 
    private long id;
    private String bar;
    private boolean isDefault;
}
```

Lombok adds below getter and setter:

```
isDefault()   // getter
setDefault()  // setter
```

And I was using below paylod to make POST call:

```
 {
     "id": 1,
     "bar": "Something interesting",
     "isDefault": true
 }
```

Now is the real problem, while making a REST call JAX-RS is looking for setIsDefault() and would never set the value for isDefault.

Comment: change the field `isDefault` to `default`

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya Will not work. The getter will be `getDefault` not `getIsDefault`. Either change the field to the wrapper class `Boolean` or don't rely on lombok to generate them automatically.

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya "default" is a keyword in Java. However a variable name without "is" prefix would solve the problem. I am looking for any alternate to keep "is".

Comment: The workaround would be to either rename the field or use Boolean instead of primitive (see https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-getter-boolean). Thanks @Michael for refering to the other question.